# What causes these artefacts in my powerpoint presentation?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

Full screen (1920x1080), this image clearly has visible issues with the font.

[Image No 1 - 1080p full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtwIw.png)

Zoomed in, and highlighted with red, these become clearer on lower resolution screens

[Image No 2 - Zoomed in image, highlighted with red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMSzd.png)

I've checked the font file - Raleway, and it's fine, and these issues only appear in Powerpoint, not Inkscape or other apps.

What could cause these issues, and is there a simple fix?

Comment: bad pixels in your monitor screen?

Comment: @Moab No, that's a screenshot - I can't see them showing dead pixels. Also they appear in animations.